# How to pass images between activities in Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

Currently I am using libgdx in android app for supporting complex animations. As switching between activities, libgdx has to load all image file again which makes black screen appear for couple of seconds.

Holding images in static variable can solve it in some case. But as data in static variables can be cleared anytime by os, I can't risk to use it. Passing objects of libgdx (textures, image actors) through intent is also not supported as they dont implement parcelable class. I haven't tried passing bitmap and converting it to pixmap on runtime.

so, Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: bro libgdx will just add another layer of complexity to your task, you can easy create your animations with native android , github full of exemples

Comment: Untrue: "But as data in static variables can be cleared anytime by os" However, Textures will only be valid with the GL context of the SurfaceView they were created in. Not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  You might be able to initialize LibGDX in a Fragment and pass the Fragment to the next Activity. Instructions for using LibGDX in a fragment are in the documentation.

Comment: @Ze Rubeus     Actually I have very little time for learning native android animations & I am using it as much as I can. But at some places, animation is too complex due to which I had to fall back for libgdx.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Actually I was referring to static variable reinitialization when process are killed by os to regain memory. I will try to initialize libgdx in fragment. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create a TextureFactory, it will not be cleared because the instance will persist on memory.

Example:

public class TextureFactory {

```
private static TextureFactory instance;

public static TextureFactory getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TextureFactory();
    }

    return instance;
}


public TextureFactory() {
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().update();
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().load("images/tiles/void.png", Texture.class);
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().load("images/tiles/dirty.png", Texture.class);
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().load("images/tiles/stone.png", Texture.class);
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().load("images/tiles/iron.png", Texture.class);
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().load("images/tiles/mythril.png", Texture.class);

    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().load("images/creatures/dwarfWalk.gif", Texture.class);
    GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().finishLoading();
}


public Texture returnTileFromType(TileType tileType){

    switch (tileType) {
    case VOID:
        return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/tiles/void.png", Texture.class);
    case DIRTY:
        return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/tiles/dirty.png", Texture.class);
    case STONE:
        return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/tiles/stone.png", Texture.class);
    case IRON_MINERAL:
        return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/tiles/iron.png", Texture.class);
    case MITHRIL_MINERAL:
        return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/tiles/mythril.png", Texture.class);
    default:
        return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/tiles/void.png", Texture.class);
    }

}

public Texture returnTextureDorf(){
    return GameAssetManager.getInstance().getManager().get("images/creatures/dwarfWalk.gif", Texture.class);
}}
```

and call it from any class using TextureFactory.getInstance()...